# When to store data to memcached

Tags: php, memcached

I am storing the result of each query to memcached and give expired for long time let say for one year. So I create each CRUD create, update, delete operation to re-cache each request.

In other words I will use memcached as first layer and database as second layer to provide data.

Am I using memcached the right way OR is memcached for temporary storage? In other words don't store each result of query for long time because it will bigger later.

Comment: Your use of memcached isn't particularly sensible, because you're reflecting the database at a single point in time, and the data in memcached will be out of data as soon as somebody inserts/updates/deletes any record in the database for that table

Comment: Generally speaking, you should use memcached should be used for caching static data from a database, and then only if it is faster than executing a database query... in the normal course of events, a well indexed database is better than using memcached

Comment: yes.. i'm storing static data from databse not the query but i'm storing them for longtime thas's why i created function to re-caching data if it any changes to make sure data in memcached up to date.

did you mean only store data for complex query ? and still querying to database for simple query. am i right ?